# How can we downsize the image in photoshop in JPEG format without affecting its resolution?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, image-quality, image-format, image-editing

I have been trying it out, I need a fixed size small image but of high resolution, so that pixels are not seen while zoomed in. I tried to change the resolution of the image by **image > image size > changing the resolution**; but, it automatically enlarged the image.
 How can it be solved?
 I just need the small sized image with high quality.

Comment: I don't fully follow - Are you looking to keep the same resolution but make the file smaller (in MB/KB)?

Comment: All images look pixellated when zoomed in. The amount of detail in an image is related to the count of pixels it contains. You cannot get a clean image if you haven't got at least one real pixel of image for each pixel displayed on the screen. So if your image is zoomed in, you have to provide it at the resolution you get at maximum zoom.

Comment: I just wanted to comment on your statement that once you changed the resolution of the image it >automatically enlarge the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change the resolution of an image and not its on-screen dimensions, **just make sure the Resample options is not chosen**

Image > Image Size (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> on Mac and <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> on Windows)

[image]

**Edit**
As one user mentioned in their comment just now, you can't make pixels appear from nothing.  Increasing an image's resolution *does not* mean it will magically look crisp at higher zoom levels.  Images will only be as sharp as they were when created.